# Mac Air iMessage problems

Tags: iphone, macos, mac, ios, continuity

I recently plugged my iPhone to my Mac. Ever since I did that, every time that I text on my iPhone it shows an icon pop up on the Mac screen, however I am not set up through messaging on my Mac. I am wondering if there is a way to stop the computer from showing that I am typing and showing who I am texting. It does not show conversation or any details, just who I am texting. It is pretty annoying.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot with this issue?

Comment: i added them to the previous post. the second picture is when i tap the icon. It shows a conversation wanted to be started with the person I was texting on my iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

You have `Handoff` turned on under `Settings`>`General`>`Handoff & Suggested Apps` on your iPhone.

Switch off `Handoff` and you shouldn't see it anymore.

Though I would be more concerned with the message to "ransom"....

Comment: that is a last name for someone lol but thank you so much for the help!!!